# PHP Cannot Add Or Update Child Field - Foreign Key Error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting an error when trying to insert some values into a MySQL Database - My page currently reads the value 'EventID' which is passed through the URL and allows me to Add Results based on that EventID.  I currently have a Drop down box which is populated by the Members within the members table.
I get this horrid error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clubresults`.`results`, CONSTRAINT `ResultEvent` FOREIGN KEY (`EventID`) REFERENCES `events` (`EventID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

I am not able to change the table structure so any help would be great appreciated.
Note - I'm currently having it echo the SQL to find the error as to why it won't insert.

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("clubresults", $con);

   // Get id from URL
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['EventID']);

    // If id is number
    if ($id > 0) 
    {
         // Get record from database
         $sql = "
            SELECT EventID
            FROM results 
            WHERE EventID = " . $id;
         $result = mysql_query($sql); 
         }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {       
  $sql="INSERT INTO results (MemberID, Score, Place)
VALUES
('".$_POST['student']."', '".$_POST['Score']."', '".$_POST['Place']."')";

$add_event = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;

echo $add_event;
}
```

HTML Form -

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> 
                        <table border="0"><p>
                        <tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Member Name: </td><td>
                        <?php
                        $query="SELECT * FROM members";

/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name=student value=''>Student Name</option>";
// printing the list box select command

while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value='$nt[MemberID]'>$nt[Firstname] $nt[Surname]</option>";
/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box 
?>

                        <tr><td>Score:</td><td> 
                        <input type="text" name="Score" maxlength="10"> 
                        <tr><td>Place:</td><td> 
                        <input type="text" name="Place" maxlength="10"> 
                        </td></tr> 
                        <tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" 
                        value="Add Result"> </th></tr> </table>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the `EventID` into your `results` record:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO results (MemberID, Score, Place, EventID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Note I have used `?` placeholders in place of your `$_POST` variables (which left you vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com)).

You should use instead prepared statements into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL, but they are not available in the ancient MySQL extension that you're using (which the community has [begun deprecating](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) anyway, so you really should stop writing new code with it); use instead either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: Thannks for the response!  So if I put

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
  $sql="INSERT INTO results (EventID, MemberID, Score, Place)
VALUES
('".$_POST['EventID']."','".$_POST['student']."', '".$_POST['Score']."', '".$_POST['Place']."')";
Will this read the EventID from the URL correctly?

Comment: Even with adding the EventID into my query with the value $_POST['EventID'] I am still receiving the error.

Comment: @user1371500: You already have an *escaped* version of the Event ID in your `$id` variable, so you could use that.  You should also, at very least, similarly escape your other variables; but please *please* ***please*** read and take note of the points I've made above.

Comment: Yes I have thank you very much, as this is a college project I can only use this style of PHP (Don't ask me why Tutor is rediculous) I now have 
   }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
  $sql="INSERT INTO results (EventID, MemberID, Score, Place)
VALUES
('".$id."','".$_POST['student']."', '".$_POST['Score']."', '".$_POST['Place']."')";

$add_event = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;

echo "Added event";
}

And I am still recieving the same error.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas :( really stuck!

Comment: @user1371500: As this is homework, you should include the [tag:homework] tag - I have taken the liberty of adding it for you.  Regarding your error, it must be that the ID you are using does not exist within the `events` table.  You must first create it there.

Comment: how do you mean create it here? It is as a field 'EventID' within the events Table! I am Grateful for your help :)

Comment: @user1371500: Before you attempt `INSERT INTO results ...`, you must first `INSERT INTO events ...` (or else use the ID of an existing event, whichever is appropriate).

Comment: Yeah I am meant to use the ID of the Event which is in the URL - Passed from the previous page.  How would one go about that?

Comment: @user1371500: The event (i.e. having that ID) must exist in the `events` table before you create the associated record in the `results` table.  You are getting this error because it does not.  Therefore, you must create a record in the `events` table, as I described in my last comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11865/discussion-between-user1371500-and-eggyal)